# GNOME-Tweaks giving `font-hinting` error

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-tweaks

I installed gnome-tweaks in ubuntu 20.04. I tried to open it by clicking it but it doesn't open. So i typed `gnome-tweaks` in terminal and it throws following error:

```
$ gnome-tweaks

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 50, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._model.load_tweaks(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakmodel.py", line 107, in load_tweaks
    mods = __import__("gtweak.tweaks", globals(), locals(), tweak_files, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_font.py", line 113, in <module>
    FontXSettingsTweak(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_font.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.btn_full.set_active(self.settings["font-hinting"] == "full")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 261, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('unknown key: %r' % (key,))
KeyError: "unknown key: 'font-hinting'"
```

Comment: See  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1017792